# Azure Stream Analytics Error :Could not deserialize the input event as Json

Tags: json, azure-stream-analytics

I am trying to create a Stream Analytics job. The message is being sent in the following format as `JSON`:

```
var message = "Name;\n" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ";" ;
```

When I am running my job I am getting the following error:

```
Could not deserialize the input event as Json. Some possible reasons: 
1) Malformed events 
2) Input source configured with incorrect serialization format
```

Comment: The error is very clear. What you posted is *not* a JSON string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your code sample, it appears your input is taking the form of:

```
Name;
  AA7509E7-D482-459B-9689-456A0F952B44;
```

then the error message you're seeing is correct, this is not valid JSON, so ASA won't be able to deserialize it.  Your JSON string should look something like this:

```
{
  "Name": "AA7509E7-D482-459B-9689-456A0F952B44"
}
```

Comment: Hi Chris = Could you help me form the Json string. I would be of great help.

Comment: Instead of creating the json with string operations, please use a Json serializer to serialize it. http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_SerializeObject.htm is an example